# Android Studio layout editor fails to catch misspelled tag

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

[image: Here is my screenshot]

Here in image my `ImageButton` tag spell incorrectly but **Android studio didn't shown me any error message** and also my **project got build successfully**. Application crash at runtime with common **Inflation error** i.e. unable to inflate xml layout.

Only way to find the error is **Layout preview** doesn't show you the **preview**.
The only way to find the error is go through each piece of code and comment/uncomment to check if its correct.

**Ouestion:**
I just wanted to know the, how can I solve this issue?? is there any better way to solve this??
because my layout almost 1000 lines long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have raised this bug **Android Open Source Project - Issue Tracker**

this is the [link](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61674#makechanges).

This issue will get fixed in earlier release of **AndroidStudio** i.e. **0.3.3**
As per there reply to my issue **(Issue id= 61674)**.

Comment: @RiteshGune BHAI on Stack again :)

Comment: sawal, nayewale answer dekhe k nahi